# Submitting form's data to a java Set

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, set, ognl

Is it possible to submit a form's data to a java Set in an action of Struts2?

Action code:

```
class TestAction extends ActionSupport{

 private Set<Integer> mySet = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();

 public TestAction(){
 }

 public String test(){

  someMethod(mySet);

 }

  ... Getters/Setters ...

}
```

Form code:

```
<form action="test.action" >
 <input name="mySet[0]" />
 <input name="mySet[1]" />
 <input name="mySet[2]" />
 <submit />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Set` is just a collection, and Struts2 has support for any type of collections internally. But for this type of collection you can't use indexes in your OGNL expressions. Try

```jsp
<form action="test.action" >
 <input name="mySet" />
 <input name="mySet" />
 <input name="mySet" />
 <s:submit />
</form>
```

Comment: @AndreaLigios If you read that right in the linked answer I used indexing via object reference using a key to identify an object in the collection. In this example there's no indexes.