# Struts2 how to bind Set<Object> from view back to controller

Tags: java, jsp, collections, binding, struts2

Let's say my controller look like this :

```
public class myController {

    private MyCustomItem acte;

    ...
    // getter and setter
}
```

and the `MyCustomItem` class have a Set of another class, like this

```
public class MyCustomItem {

    private Set<AnotherClass> signataires;

    ...
    // getter and setter
}
```

Finally, the `AnotherClass` item have some String attributes.

What I want to do is, from the view linked to my controller, set those String attributes when I submit a form, so I wrote my `view.jsp` like this :

```
<!-- some html before -->
<s:form namespace="/my/namespace" action="MyController_execute">
<s:iterator value="acte.signataires" status="signaStatus">
    <s:hidden name="id" value="%{id}" />
    <s:property value="collectivite.nom"/>
    <s:textfield name="acte.signataires(%{#signaStatus.index}).commentaire" cssStyle="width:250px;"/>
</s:iterator>
<s:submit/>
</s:form>
```

Afte I submitted the form, in my controller if I try to get some values from my Set<> `acte.signataires`, they are null :

```
for (AnotherClass signataire : acte.getSignataires()) {
    System.out.println(signataire.getCommentaire()); // this print NULL
}
```

any help on this ? Is my jsp mapping bad ? I also tried a very simple syntax like `<s:textfield name="commentaire" cssStyle="width:250px;"/>` but it won't work either

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27636685/573032 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/24449774/573032

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the property signataires to be a Set ?
I suggest to you to use an ArrayList so that you can access each element by the index (signataires[0], signataires[1], etc...).
Using an ArrayList then you could do in this way:

```
<s:form namespace="/my/namespace" action="MyController_execute">
<s:iterator value="acte.signataires" status="signaStatus">
    <s:hidden name="id" value="%{id}" />
    <s:property value="collectivite.nom"/>
    <INPUT type="text" name="acte.signataires[<s:property value="%{#signaStatus.index}"/>].commentaire" cssStyle="width:250px;"/>
</s:iterator>
<s:submit/>
</s:form>
```

Comment: I cannot change my Set<> to a List, but I did a "copy" of it as a List in my controller like this : `List<Anotherclass> copyList = new ArrayList<>(signataires)` and the binding to it works as you suggested. Thank you, but if anyone have an answer on how to use a Set, I'll be grateful